# Best way to capture screen time and press events using React Native Expo and Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-analytics

My group and I are currently working on a mobile app using expo-cli and firebase as the backend. One of the requirements is we need to get users' screen time and record how frequently users press certain buttons. According to expo [firebase documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-analytics/), it only supports limited Firebase Analysis. We were wondering what would be the best way to use Firebase Analytics with Expo to capture screen time and button pressed frequencies.

Comment: What library are you using for the navigation?

Comment: @Y.Gherbi We're using react-native-navigation

Comment: Did my answer help you out? Or did you find a solution in general?

Answer (score 3):

**Screen Tracking**

Screen tracking in React Native is different than in a native app since some navigation libraries run inside *one* `Activity/Viewcontroller`.

Assuming you are using [`react-native-navigation`](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation), which *does* have full native navigation support you can handle screen tracking like this.

```js
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

Navigation.events().registerComponentDidAppearListener(async ({ componentName, componentType }) => {
  if (componentType === 'Component') {
    await analytics().logScreenView({
      screen_name: componentName,
      screen_class: componentName,
    });
  }
});
```

Look [here](https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/screen-tracking#react-native-navigation) for the documentation

If you are using [`react-navigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/) you can still work around the lack of native screen support by hooking into the events that are provided.

```js
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const App = () => {
  const routeNameRef = React.useRef();
  const navigationRef = React.useRef();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() => {
        routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name;
      }}
      onStateChange={async () => {
        const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
        const currentRouteName = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name;

        if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
          await analytics().logScreenView({
            screen_name: currentRouteName,
            screen_class: currentRouteName,
          });
        }
        routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
      }}
    >
      ...
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/) you can find a full example starter app.

**Button Press Events**

For logging press events there's a lot of [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage#custom-events) on the RNFirebase website.

A simple example to track a custom event that could be an `onPress` or anything would look like this:

```js
import react, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';

function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="Add To Basket"
        onPress={async () =>
          await analytics().logEvent('onPressAddToBasket', {
            id: 3745092,
            item: 'Your product name',
            description: ['round neck', 'long sleeved'],
            size: 'L',
            wheneverYouWantToTrack: true,
          })
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: @ClubSand Could you select this as the correct answer if it helped you out? Makes it easier for others who have the same question to find an answer